# get value with watir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to get the value of the first textarea element. I tried with this code, but each time I get an error. I can't find a solution to my problem, even though I read a lot of documentation on the internet.

```
browser.div(:class => "tabbertab").text_field(:id=>"ic0-3316955").value

<div class="tabbertab " title="">
    <h2>
           <textarea id="ic0-3316955" onfocus="copy(this);" rows="3" style="width:98%;">
        http://xxxx.org/nwqqy7ilwqdo
    </textarea>
    <div id="c0-3316955" class="btndiv">
        copy
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tabbertab tabbertabhide" title="">
    <h2>
        Link for forums
    </h2>
    <textarea id="ic1-3316955" onfocus="copy(this);" rows="3" style="width:98%;">
        [URL=http://xxxx.org/nwqqy7ilwqdo]para.mp4 - 7…
    </textarea>
```

Error:

> /home/zyriuse/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:513:in `assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:class=>"tabbertab", :tag_name=>"div"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

Comment: Based on your error, the page element can't be located.  Is the textarea being dynamically loaded or in a frame?  Also, there's a trailing space in the class attribute here: `<div class="tabbertab " title="">`

Comment: @orde is probably onto something. Is there more to your HTML? If the above code is in an iframe you will have to account for that: browser.iframe(:id, "some_id").textarea.... Or if things are loaded at different times you'll probably need a .wait_until_present. Interestingly, the trailing space in the class name seems to be ignored by Watir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the last element you must to use

```
browser.textarea(:index,4).value
```

and change number '4' if you have any value.

Comment: For the code you supplied in your question, you would need `(:index,1)`. But I would recommend latching onto the id as I described in the comment below my answer. It is much easier to quickly construct a Watir command using the id. Also, if my answer worked for you, can you please accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply type

```
browser.textarea(:id, "ic1-3316955").value
```

to get the text contained within that `textarea`. Also, note that recent versions of Watir-Webdriver want you to use `textarea` and not `text_field` for a `textarea` tag (the ability to use `text_field` for a `textarea` will be deprecated at some point in the future).

(EDIT) HOWEVER, I just put together a quick web page using your code and was able to get both your Watir command and mine to produce identical results:

```
irb(main):006:0> browser.div(:class => "tabbertab").text_field(:id=>"ic0-3316955").value
=> "        http://xxxx.org/nwqqy7ilwqdo\n    "

irb(main):007:0> browser.textarea(:id=>"ic0-3316955").value
=> "        http://xxxx.org/nwqqy7ilwqdo\n    "
```

So, while I think my solution is a bit cleaner and more straightforward than your original attempt, I'm not really sure why your effort was unsuccessful since it did work for me.

Comment: for get the first value i need to do browser.textarea.value
 but how i can get the last value ?

Comment: Similar to the first value. If your HTML element has an id, always use that because ids are unique on the page. So `browser.textarea(:id, "ic1-3316955").value` will give you the value contained in that second textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Hey In order to retrieve the value of the Text_Field u can use the follwoing method to retrieve it

```
getContents
for Example
@ie.text_field(:id,'sample').getContents
will return the value of the textfield.
```